# Map, findIndex and filter combined

Tags: javascript

I came [across](https://github.com/survivejs-demos/redux-demo/blob/45970b6abf352e34002c4e0299df85c983e437d4/kanban_app/app/components/Lane.jsx#L89) a function below and not completely sure what it is doing.
What is the purpose of `.filter(note => note)` specifically?

```
laneNotes: props.lane.notes.map(id => state.notes[
  state.notes.findIndex(note => note.id === id)
]).filter(note => note)
```

Also does `filter` get executed for each `notes` or only once after all `notes` are looped over by `map`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.filter(note => note)` will filter all `falsy` values. It's equivalent to: `.filter(Boolean)`

```
Also does filter get executed for each notes 
or only once after all notes are looped over by map?
```

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function

```js
console.log([0, 2, '', false, null, true, undefined].filter(item => item));
console.log([0, 2, '', false, null, true, undefined].filter(Boolean));
```

All [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values in javascript:

- `null`
- `false`
- `0`
- `''` / `""`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`

Answer (score 2):

It checks to see if `note` is truthy - if not truthy, the element doesn't get included in the computed `laneNotes`.

For example:

```js
console.log(
  [0, 1, 2].filter(num => num)
);
```

The code in question, put more simply, looks like this:

```
laneNotes: props.lane.notes.map((id) => {
  const foundIndex = state.notes.findIndex(note => note.id === id);
  return state.notes[foundIndex];
}).filter(note => note);
```

It uses `findIndex` to find the matching `note` - but if no matching `note` is found, `foundIndex` will be -1, so `state.notes[foundIndex]` will be undefined. The purpose of the `.filter` function is to keep those `undefined`s out of the result.

Comment: @@maxflow It might not be truthy because `findIndex` might have returned `-1`, whose index does not exist in the array - see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Simply- `.filter(n => n)` removes empty (non-truthy) values and yes- it loops across every item in mapped (returned by `.map`) array

You should definitely see the docs: [mozilla.org -> filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) :)